# Discord.js remove certain role's permission to send messages in a channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
discussionChannel.rolePermissions('590449138093522955').add('SEND_MESSAGES: true')
AND 
discussionChannel.rolePermissions('590449138093522955').remove('SEND_MESSAGES: true')
```

send the error: RangeError: Invalid permission string or number.

discussionChannel is a valid text channel. That's literally all I know. For some reason getting a Permissions for a role and then trying to change whether or not it can send messages is not working.

Comment: `'SEND_MESSAGES: true'` might need to be `'SEND_MESSAGES'`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Permissions.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=add) and [`Permissions.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=remove) take any amount of [PermissionResolvable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PermissionResolvable)s. These can be a string containing a valid [permission flag](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS), the number of the permission, [Permissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions) themselves, or an array of elements matching any of the preceding options.

`'SEND_MESSAGES: true'` is not a PermissionResolvable.

Use just the flag (or number of the permission), for example `'SEND_MESSAGES'`.